# Jooq- Is there a way I can batch execute and return inserted ids?

Tags: java, spring, jooq

I build up a list of these inserts with Jooq:

```
//loop

inserts.add(
   context
      .insertInto(MY_TABLE, MY_TABLE.STATUS, MY_TABLE.NAME)
      .select(context.select(
         val("some status"),
         val("some name"),
      ))
      //some filtering logic
    
      .returningResult(MY_TABLE.ID)
)
```

Then I batch execute:

```
Iterators.partition(inserts.iterator(), 50)
      .forEachRemaining(inserts -> {
      sql.batch(inserts).execute();
     
      //get the inserted ids

});
```

The inserts work fine, but I can't work out how to get the inserted rows/ids back. The filter logic will mean that some inserts will be "ignored" because there could be existing rows which already match the criteria.

I am dealing with concurrency issues so I can't simply run a separate select query to figure out what needs to be or has been inserted.